# how to decrease or increase a number bu pressing the button Java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys i've made buttons of '+' and '-' and there is a number which i need to increase or decrease while pressing the + or -, here my code but it isn't working. Will be glad if you can help me.

thank you!

```
button class="plus_minus"></button><span class="number">1</span><button class="minus_plus"></button>

my JS

const plus = document.querySelector('.plus_minus'),minus = document.querySelector('.minus_plus');

let number = parseInt(document.querySelector('.number'));

plus.addEventListener('click',() => {number++ ;});

minus.addEventListener('click',() => {number--;

});
```

Comment: Can you share what's going wrong? Are you having any error in console?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I would suggest this:

HTML :

```
<button class="minus">-</button><span id="number">1</span><button class="plus">+</button>
```

One class for "minus" button and one class for "plus" button. In your code you didn't differenciate them.

JS:

```
const minus = document.querySelector('.minus')
const plus = document.querySelector('.plus');

plus.addEventListener('click',() => document.getElementById("number").textContent++);

minus.addEventListener('click',() => document.getElementById("number").textContent--);
```

Add two listeners that directly increment/decrement the value.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your code and it will help you.

```
let number = parseInt(document.querySelector('.number'));
```

`document.querySelector('.number')` returns element with "number" classname , not it's content text.
`document.querySelector('.number').innerText` returns the element's content text.

```
let oldVal = 1;
let newVal = oldVal++;
// output: newVal = 1    oldVal = 2
```

```
let oldVal = 1;
let newVal = ++oldVal;
// output: newVal = 2    oldVal = 2
```

```js
const plus = document.querySelector('.plus_minus'),
  minus = document.querySelector('.minus_plus');

let number_el = document.querySelector('.number');

plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let val = parseInt(number_el.innerText);
  number_el.innerText = ++val;
});

minus.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let val = parseInt(number_el.innerText);
  number_el.innerText = --val;
});
```

```html
<button class="plus_minus">+</button>
<span class="number">1</span>
<button class="minus_plus">-</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you `number` variable is reference of the `span` element.
You should get the value (innerHTML) of that

```
let number = parseInt(document.querySelector('.number').innerHTML);
```

In the event listener you should update the DOM (innertHTML of span)  again after the value is updated.

```
    plus.addEventListener('click',() => {
     number++ ;
     document.querySelector('.number').innerHTML = number;
    });

    minus.addEventListener('click',() => {
     number--;
     document.querySelector('.number').innerHTML = number;
    });
```